# Equally spacing string while also aligning them

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I have a ListView and the top most item looks as follows.

```
ID         FIRST NAME         LAST NAME      DOB            SS         PHONE NUMBER
```

Now under these item I want to place other items that actually contain this info

```
ID         FIRST NAME         LAST NAME      DOB            SS              PHONE NUMBER
1          Paul               Lopez          some date      some number     some number
```

I cant seem to figure out how to align these items so that the length of the string doesn't effect the alignment (i.e if u add two letter to Paul it won't push everything in front forward). Here is what i have.

```
String headerString = ID         FIRST NAME         LAST NAME      DOB            SS              PHONE NUMBER;
private void updateEmployees(){
    employeeLV.getItems().clear();
    employeeLV.getItems().add(headerString);
    for (EmployeeInfo employee : dateBaseHelper.getAllEmployees()){
        employeeLV.getItems().add(
                employee.getId() + spacer
                + employee.getfName() + spacer
                + employee.getlName() + spacer + spacer
                + employee.getDob() + spacer + spacer
                + employee.getSsNum() + spacer + spacer
                + employee.getPhoneNumber());
    }
}
```

I do realize this is a poor attempt and I hope you guys can help.

Comment: Are you using `printf`? It handles padding and alignment for you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with printf?

Comment: @4castle code is up.

Comment: You could use `String.format("%-15d", employee.getId())` for example to pad the string ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)), but I think the correct answer to your question would use the proper tools from JavaFX, which I'm not familiar with.

Comment: could you give an example

Comment: @4castle How would you use `printf` in a `ListView`? `printf` is a stream-based method.

Comment: It looks like you really need a [`TableView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html) here. There is a [tutorial on the Oracle site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm#CJAGAAEE) and another popular one from [Code Makery](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/)

Comment: @James_D Thanks this is just what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a [TableView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html). With a TableView you are able to make auto-aligned columns. So you can just insert values (of different types) and let JavaFX do the alignment for you.

You may have a look at [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm) about TableViews.

Please consider to implement your employee to have [SimpleIntegerProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/SimpleIntegerProperty.html), [SimpleStringProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/SimpleStringProperty.html) and [SimpleObjectProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/SimpleObjectProperty.html) as fields instead of int, String and Date. This would make using a TableView much easier.